# PHP Hash wont match bash

Tags: php, hash

im new to coding and im doing php hasher as:

```
<?php
$qualhash = ($_POST['userhash']);
echo $qualhash;
echo "<br />";
echo "SHA-256: ";
echo hash('sha256', '$qualhash');
echo "<br />";
echo "SHA-512: ";
echo hash('sha512', '$qualhash');
echo "<br />";
echo "SHA1: ";
echo hash('sha1', '$qualhash');
echo "<br />";
echo "MD5: ";
echo hash('md5', '$qualhash');
echo "<br />";
echo "RIPEMD160: ";
echo hash('ripemd160', '$qualhash');
echo "<br />";
echo "WHIRLPOOL: ";
echo hash('whirlpool', '$qualhash');
echo "<br />";
?>
```

Hash Results are:

teste

SHA-256: 58b463a26133708da575a40ff11fb0a6e065c51af9266f650a149187292f11a9

SHA-512: 9cd1f970a2a9207b15ea9fd4d8306632f4436a5fe95e23646619f04fc1e3530a171a25689efeb928d00093f783ccf1f48aeac735b98e109cc242fe324595b522

SHA1: a25b45a7b7518935c20d2ad0f8a62eb3d951e3dd

MD5: 0b71582d7e2b1c4ada16ea5dbe5f3778

RIPEMD160: e7d552e210753b86bacfa02d2d6f6e208d3640c1

WHIRLPOOL: 8a7a23781d9bfd6ab2ee3e5afebe38a78c84bff018a2f896ea1efae01d7d1ffbaee049c85f8e8461c2438aa8e84ff10ea2790787c2b07b74f42415bd30eb82c5

I also have a html form to submit the string:

```
<form action="hasher2.php" method="post">
 <p>Text : <input type="text" name="userhash" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Terminal spits out:

```
$ echo -n teste | md5sum
698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b  -
$
```

Any idea why this behavior? What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: `'$qualhash'` is a string, not a variable. Remove the single quotes and pass `$qualhash` to the hash function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending the string `'$qualhash'`, not `teste`

Try replace

```
echo hash('sha256', '$qualhash');
```

with

```
echo hash('sha256', $qualhash);
```

and do the same everywhere you call the function.

You can check

```
$ echo -n \$qualhash | md5sum
0b71582d7e2b1c4ada16ea5dbe5f3778  -

$ echo -n teste | md5sum
698dc19d489c4e4db73e28a713eab07b  -
```